# TYPO3 6.2 - fe login not working

Tags: typo3

In one of my installations the frontend login does not work. TYPO3 6.2.30. In a fresh installation it works, so there must be a problem in this specific installation. I tried to deinstall all extensions but i cant find the problem. There is simple no login ...

I need to debug the problem but the FrontendLoginController of felogin only uses this line of code:

```
$this->userIsLoggedIn = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->loginUser;
```

so actual the core manages the login all by itself. In which classes can i find the relevant code which manages the login?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, i found the problem: Someone activated the option "Login behavior: Disable Login" in the root page. This will be inherited through the whole tree.

I found the problem after installing the dev log extension which logs every step of the login process. So i was able to see that the user sucessful logged in and gets immediatly logged out again.

Well, I feel incredible stupid in this moment ... I searched for the problem more than six hours ...

Answer (score 0):

typical errors for login: cookies and sessions and storagepid.
are the cookies set as expected?  (domain? name? lifetime? configurable in the Install tool)
are session data stored?
have you configured the correct page where the FE-users records are stored? especially if the FE-users can register themself: are the records stored in the correct page? do they get the correct status? (unhidden, correct FE-group)
remember: no login without group. have the user records a group assigned?

but if you prefer to debug php: the API (here 6.2) is documented and you might debug here http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/62/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_felogin_1_1_controller_1_1_frontend_login_controller.html

Comment: Thanks for your answert! It worked in a fresh TYPO3 on the same server. So i hope i made the correct steps: fresh group, fresh user with this group, PID of sys folder in flexform ... No cookie and no session because no login possible. Forget password works, i can change the password in frontend.  
This class manages mainly redirects ... authentification is done in this line: $this->userIsLoggedIn = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->loginUser; - not very helpful :-) I would need to know where the real authentification is done. Perhaps there is a problem with salted password ...